# How can I create make pattern rule that can expand the target as a dependency?

Tags: gnu-make

I'm trying to create a makefile that has rule something like:

```
~/$ cat > Makefile << EOF
FILES=a b c
$(FILES): % : src/%/%
        @echo "$@ $<"
EOF
```

Running the command gives:

```
~/$ make a
make: *** No rule to make target `src/a/%', needed by `a'.  Stop.
```

And what I'd like to see is:

```
~/$ make a
a src/a/a
```

How do a create rule to expand the second `%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,
[secondary expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion)
might help.
For example:

```
FILES=a b c
.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(FILES): % : src/$$*/$$*
    @echo "$@ $<"
```

If your GNU make's version is 3.80 or lower, `$*` might not work.
In that case, `$@` and some text manipulation might be needed instead.

Comment: Wow.  That nailed it.  Although I'm very dissapointed I couldn't understand what the [automatic variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$*` was all about.

Comment: Glad it helped :-)
In static pattern rule(`$(FILES): % : src/$$*/$$*`), `$*` (ought to) denotes `%`.